# How many different ways can you order a binary code (only 1s and 0s) if there is 5 of one and 6 of the other?

Tags: problem-solving, binary

If you have 6 0's and 5 1's, like in binary, how many different ways can you order them?

Also, there is a popup saying that the question appears subjective. Is it?

Comment: $\frac{(6+5)!}{6!\times5!}$

Comment: @barakmanos coould you explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

You have 11 places to fill, and you can put five ones in the eleven places, the rest will be zeroes. Once you ***choose*** (*hint, hint*) the positions of the ones, the zeroes are fixed. Each choice of ones will give exactly one unique ordering.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh I get it! Selected as solution!